# Safari toggle scale image jerking

Tags: html, css, safari

While working on a project in which it is required to zoom in on a really high res image (~6000px x 4000px) to discover highlighted parts in the image, I came across a Safari issue while scaling the image to a certain position (assigning top and left to specific values).

The issue is that the scaling is really jerky, only in Safari. I have found that when taking out the specific top and left positions it scales smoothly to the origin that has been set (which is "0 0" = top-left).

I have created a JSBin for better understanding: https://jsbin.com/lukumiw/edit?html,css,js,output

(I know that toggling the class removes the translateX, but that is not an issue at that point).

So my question is, is there a solution to having a smooth scaling with specific positions or is it purely Safari not processing the block of code as it should? It looks as if it's scaling with a staircase effect - while top and left are changing, that's how it's scaling - if that makes sense.